# avrdude cannot connect to USBasp under non-root despite a udev rule

Tags: fedora, usb, udev

Root works:

```
[root@host14 rules.d]# avrdude -c USBASP -p m328p

avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Non-root does not:

```
[user0@host14 ~]$ avrdude -c USBASP -p m328p
avrdude: Warning: cannot open USB device: Permission denied
avrdude: error: could not find USB device "USBasp" with vid=0x16c0 pid=0x5dc

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

The rule has been added as follows into `/etc/udev/rules.d/21-usbasp.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="05dc", GROUP="users", MODE="0666"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://andreasrohner.at/posts/Electronics/How-to-fix-device-permissions-for-the-USBasp-programmer/#permanent_solution